# clearInterval - something's amiss

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

It seems that everyone has a few problems with clearInterval. I have built a slider that allows people to hover a click on arrows. The banner also rotates ever few seconds. I want to be able to have the auto-rotate turn off after someone clicks on one of the arrows.

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
    var intvl = 0;
    intvl = setInterval(heroTransitionNext, 2000);
    $('.rightArrow').click(function(){
       window.clearInterval(intvl);
    });
});
```

EDIT:

Here is the function it is calling:

```
function heroTransitionNext() {
    $('.HP-hero li').filter(':visible').fadeOut('normal', function () {
        if ($(this).next().length != 0) {
            activeZone = parseInt(activeZone) + 1;
            $(this).next().fadeIn('normal', heroNavHighlight(activeZone));
        } else {
            activeZone = 1;
            $('.HP-hero li:first-child').fadeIn('normal', heroNavHighlight(activeZone));
        }
        $(this).hide();
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what your `heroTransitionNext` function does, but this code [*should* work](http://jsfiddle.net/EtPRq/).  I can't see a problem with the code you have posted. Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: I agree with @Lix. A quick fiddle shows the code should work http://jsfiddle.net/rmJtD/. So the problem might be with `heroTransitionNext`.

Comment: So, what exactly is the issue?  You explain what the is supposed to do, but not what it *does* do.

Comment: It does nothing. There is no error AND it does not stop rotating. I posted the heroTransitionNext function for reference as well. I have been banging my head against the wall on this one for the better part of an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the animation you can use `jquery`'s `.stop()` but not sure whether it'll solve the problem or not that you are facing (didn't visualize) but you can give it a try

```
$('.HP-hero li').stop(1,1); // or try $('.HP-hero li').stop()
window.clearInterval(intvl);
```

As `say2joe` said that `clearInterval` will just stop the function from invoking next time but it won't clear the current queue (he is right) so in that case `stop` could be used.

[**About Stop**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as the answer, because it was the closest. Basically, it was a scope issue in which I needed to call window.intvl to make it work. Thanks for helping me think through this one.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much work your heroTransitionNext function is doing, it may still be executing even though the interval is cleared -- in other words, clearing the interval will stop the function from being invoked -- but, any instance of the function(s) executing in memory will continue to execute until finished.

To be more clear, here's a use case (you can check this out yourself by using a profiler in Firebug or Developer Tools):

heroTransitionNext execution time is 2.1 seconds.
clearInterval is invoked 6.1 seconds after setInterval is invoked.
At 6.1 seconds, heroTransitionNext has been invoked four times. The first three executions have completed, however, the fourth will not complete until it finishes executing (at 8.1 seconds since setInterval was called). Note: In this use case, each successive invokation will execute while the last invokation's execution is still continuing (for 100 more ms) -- in other words, you'll have execution overlap from 2 to 2.1, 4 to 4.1, and 6 to 6.1 second intervals.

If the function takes longer to execute than the interval set, use a recursive function with setTimeout(). The following link will give you a good example.

Also, a good reference for explanation is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval.

Comment: I just posted the heroTransistionNext function as well. I don't see any reason it would be doing that.

Comment: The above use case is purely hypothetical... I did not actually execute your function... so, I don't know it actual execution time. But, this is probably the problem.

Comment: Please note that the default time for jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() is 400ms. So, the function will take probably at least 800ms to execute -- but, probably much longer with the DOM lookups, etc.